# Problem with Multi directional sprites in Monogame

Tags: sprite, monogame, angle, direction

I'm trying to implement multi directional sprites like they are in old FPS Shooters (Wolfenstein 3D or Doom).

My sprite has 8 directions. OffSetX is the offset that gets the right sprite from my spritesheet (0 = facing towrds the camera, 1 = facing towrds/right, 2 = facing right and so on...).

I have a 3D camera implemented, so my environment is in 3D, but the sprites are billboards.

Since hours now I'm trying to find a working example but somehow nothing works properly.
Here ist my code so far:

```
int offsetX = 0;

Vector3 camPos = GameScreen.camera.view.Forward;
Vector3 ownPos = position;

double dx = ownPos.X - camPos.X;
double dy = ownPos.Z - camPos.Z;
double a2 = Math.Atan2(dy, dx);

float angle = (float)((180 / Math.PI) * a2);

if (angle < 0) angle = angle + 360;

            switch (angle)
            {
                case float n when (n >= 292.5f && n < 337.5f):
                    offsetX = 7;
                    break;
                case float n when (n >= 22.5f && n < 67.5f):
                    offsetX = 1;
                    break;
                case float n when (n >= 67.5f && n < 112.5f):
                    offsetX = 2;
                    break;
                case float n when (n >= 112.5f && n < 157.5f):
                    offsetX = 3;
                    break;
                case float n when (n >= 157.5f && n < 202.5f):
                    offsetX = 4;
                    break;
                case float n when (n >= 202.5f && n < 247.5f):
                    offsetX = 5;
                    break;
                case float n when (n >= 247.5f && n < 292.5f):
                    offsetX = 6;
                    break;
                case float n when (n >= 337.5f || n < 22.5f):
                    offsetX = 0;
                    break;
            }
```

Somehow the results are broken here. The angle does not get calculated properly. At 359 degrees it jumps back to zero and when it is greater than 5, it jumps to 360 degrees.

I also tried it with:

```
double sin = camPos.X * ownPos.Z - ownPos.X * camPos.Z;
double cos = camPos.X * ownPos.X + camPos.Z * ownPos.Z;
double a2 = Math.Atan2(sin, cos);
```

but this also does not work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out.

Just take

```
Vector3 camPos = GameScreen.camera.position;
```

Now the sprites roatate as they should.

Is there maybe a more elegant solution?